# Return error message login Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I'm working on a login form in Wordpress.

I have this form :

**page.php**

```
wp_login_form( array(
    'redirect'       => site_url( '/nos-produits' ), 
    'label_username' => 'Identifiant',
    'label_password' => 'Mot de passe',
    'label_remember' => 'Se souvenir de moi',
    'label_log_in'   => 'Se connecter',
    'form_id'        => 'login-form',
    'id_username'    => 'user-login',
    'id_password'    => 'user-pass',
    'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
    'remember'       => false, 
        'value_remember' => false 
    ) );

   if(isset($error)) {
    echo $error;
    }
```

Instead of redirecting on wp-login page I wrote this code

**function.php**

```
add_action('login_redirect', 'redirect_login', 10, 3);

function redirect_login($redirect_to, $url, $user) {

 if($user->errors['invalid_username']){
    wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url').'/our-products/');
    $error = "Wrong username";
    return $error;

}

exit;
}
```

So basically When I type a wrong username name I'll be redirected to page.php and thanks to the function, $error will be displayed below the form.

But with my code it does not work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You probably do not want to use exit there: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: "But with my code it does not work." - What doesn't work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: The message doesn't display in page.php. I'm trying with session, it works but when I load the page without submiting the error message always appears

Comment: I just want to display $error from the function to page.php